# Google chrome wants to use the keychain password frequently

Tags: macos, google-chrome, password, keychain

Google chrome wants to use the keychain password frequently in my mac system(OSX version 10.9.2).

Before updating the OS to new version, the applications like Textedit, Preview are used to ask the password while accessing them. If I click the cancel button twice, the popup will be disappeared. But, after updating to new OS version, a popup saying `Google chrome wants to use the keychain password` without any reason. 
[image]

I need to click the cancel button for eight to twenty times to disappear the popup. While writing this question that dialog box appears three times. Sometimes, I keep that alert box to the bottom like below.

[image]

I tried deleting the password for Chrome in keychain, as suggested in [this](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/03/04/google-chrome-wants-to-use-your-confidential-information-store-in-the-keychain/) link. But, no use.

Comment: Have you tried entering the password instead of cancelling it each time?

Comment: @Rob, I entered the password one time and after sometime, it asks the password again. But, I tried it only one time. Ok I'll try to enter the password and let you know what happens. thanks.

Comment: @Rob, I tried entering password. But it asks the password for every after some time(say 0.5 hr).

Comment: Doesn't the website's session expire in 30 minutes?

Comment: @Rob, I don't think so. I'm currently in apple.SE. Does it's session expire in 30 minutes? I generally use Chrome for only SE sites, gmail and Cricinfo.

Comment: Read this answer to see if it helps you http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127155/google-chrome-vs-my-keychain

Comment: @Buscar웃, yes it works.

Comment: OK than, your question will be closed as duplicate, nothing personal :)

Comment: @Buscar웃, I already voted to close ;)